# Get output from method for form submitting in method for form validation in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a validation method which ends like this:

```
function validateForm()
{
    //do some validation
    document.imgUploadForm.submit();
}
```

With this, the method calls a method for submitting a form which is in a controller.

Currently, the method for handling the form returns an ActionResult.

Is there a way: HandleForm() to return JsonResult and then validateForm() to get the returned object and do stuff with it?

I tried setting JsonResult as a return type to HandleForm() and then writing:

```
var x = document.imgUploadForm.submit();
```

but x is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ajax on the client side , if you are using jQuery do :

```
$.getJSON("url",{input1:"value",input2:"value"},function(data){
   doSomethingWithTheDatas(data);
});
```

if your goal is to send something to the server , get a response and handle the response client side.

EDIT : i assume HandleForm() is server side or the question makes little sense.

Comment: I can't use Ajax. I'm calling the method in a way that you can see in my question.

Comment: well why are you doing x = ... then ? you obviously expect a result back from the server , what do you expect .submit() to return ?

Comment: If the output from FormPosted() is an object, how to get it in validateMethod()?

Comment: where is the method FormPosted() in your question ?

Comment: form.submit() will submit your form directly through a post. The browser will send a POST request to the server, receive a reply and replace the page you were on with that reply. The original Javascript will be unloaded from the browser at this point. 

Ajax sends the POST through Javascript and can receive a reply in Javascript (without unloading the page) which you can then process any way you want. Ajax is what you want. If you can run Javascript, why can't you use ajax?

Comment: Clarification: You might mean that you can't use Jquery, which doesn't matter. Ajax requests are native to Javascript and can be used with whatever library you're using, or you can write your own functions for it.